# Does the Coxeter group $C(D_n)$ have any "proper reflection quotients" except $C(A_{n-1})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, coxeter-groups

Here, a *reflection quotient* is a surjective homomorphism between Coxeter groups mapping reflections to reflections. A reflection quotient $C(\Delta) \to C(\Gamma)$ is *proper* if it is not injective and $\Gamma$ is not the single vertex graph.

An example of a proper reflection quotient is the homomorphism $C(D_n) \to C(A_{n-1})$ identifying two leaves of $D_n$. Are there any other reflection quotients $C(D_n) \to C(\Gamma)$? If yes, which ones?

Note that $C(A_{k-1}) \cong S_k$ does not have any proper reflection quotients for any $k$. This can be seen by noting that if $k \neq 4$ the only proper normal subgroup of $S_k$ is simple of index two, and if $k = 4$ the only other quotient is in fact $S_3$, but not in a reflection-preserving manner. Because $C(A_{n-1})$ is not only a reflection quotient but also a quite big reflection subgroup (i.e. a subgroup generated by reflections) of $C(D_n)$, it seems likely that the answer to my question is *no*.

Literature about the topic of what I called reflection quotients would be greatly appreciated, as I did not find any.

Comment: May I ask in what context this question arises?

Comment: @DavidSheard Sure. I'm considering subgroups of mapping class groups of surfaces generated by Dehn twists, and want to investigate whether they are "geometrically isomorphic" to an Artin group (i.e. the isomorphism maps standard generators of the Artin group to Dehn twists). One such group (a proper "geometric quotient" of $A(D_n)$) appears not to be, and I could deduce this from a negative answer to my question, as I have a way to exclude $A(A_{n-1})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is indeed no, unless $n = 4$. This is shown in the article *The normal subgroups of finite and affine Coxeter groups* by George Maxwell. In Table 3 he lists the reflection quotients of $D_n$ (which are just the mentioned ones), and an additional reflection quotient $C(A_2)$ in the case $n = 4$.

See also my [answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/421044/147690) for a more detailed and more general answer. That thread also contains answers for other classes of Coxeter groups.